# Ajax ToolKits and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I Install Ajax controls ToolKits in Asp.net Mvc project When I working in Razor!
When I work on razor there is no ant tools Like Web form instead when you select html.cs after create new project in MVC

Comment: That is the beauty of MVC : ) You write your own clean ajax code as needed. You have full control over it. you can use jQuery to do your ajax calls. It is simple. Just search for jQuery ajax in SO and you will find a ton of samples

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc+ajax+toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. ASP.NET MVC does not support the Ajax toolkit because they are designed for WebForms projects. As the commentor above mentioned, there are other ways to add reusable code to an MVC application.